# Is there any legitimate use for bare strings in PHP?

Tags: php, string, arrays, key, bare

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405482/is-it-okay-to-use-arraykey-in-php) got me thinking about bare strings.

When PHP sees a string that's not enclosed in quotes, it first checks to see if it's a constant. If not, it just assumes it's a string and goes on anyway. So for example if I have

```
echo $foo[bar];
```

If there's a constant called bar it uses that for the array key, but if not then it treats bar as a bare string, so it behaves just like

```
echo $foo["bar"];
```

This can cause all kinds of problems if at some future date a constant is added with the same name.

My question is, is there any situation in which it actually makes sense to use a bare string?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nope, I can not see a single instance where it would make sense, and it always is dangerous. Using strings without quotes should absolutely be reserved to address constants. I don't understand how the inventors of PHP could decide to introduce this ridiculous behaviour at  all - it makes the proper use of constants almost impossible (because if you try to access a constant that has not been defined, PHP will silently and stupidly generate a string) without giving *any* benefit.

Comment: +1, I agree with you Pekka, and just because PHP is forgiving enough to convert the bare string into a literal for you, doesn't mean you should get into a habit of using it.

Comment: @Anthony true, plus (I edited my answer a bit) it massively sabotages the use of constants - you can never really rely on their being set, and have to check them using `defined`. The proper way would be to throw a fatal error if a constant has not been defined.

Comment: Well, you just have to report warning-level errors and vigilantly fix them.  But it's still a PITA.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't probably count as legitimate, but my friend's tweetable proof-of-concept MVC framework, [TweetMVC](http://github.com/jeremeamia/TweetMVC) eschews quotes in a few spots to squeeze a few more characters in, e.g.:

```
foreach(c('mod')as$f)require"t/$f.php";@list($c,$m,$a)=explode('/',@$_GET[r],3);$c=$c?:c('dc');$o=(@include"c/$c.php")?@new$c($m,$a):e(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only time you would use a bare string as a key is if it's been previously used in [`define()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) for a constant.