# Why "echo value" print 'value' instead of an error?

Tags: php

I figured out that the line

```
echo value;
```

print "value" in the page, when there is no '$' symbol and there is no define.

Also, it doesn't work if there is a space in it, i.e. :

```
echo hel lo;
```

doesn't work.

How is this possible, and is it dangerous to use this method instead of using " " ?

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: `echo value` should print a warning, that no constant `value` is defined, assuming you mean `"value"`

Comment: you need to turn on php error reporting to see whats happening.

Comment: @king_nak a notice, along with the values as it would convert the values to strings.

Comment: @stovent if you want to echo a lot of values you need to add comma instead of space ! `echo hel, lo;` instead of `echo hel lo;`

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406006/is-there-any-legitimate-use-for-bare-strings-in-php) is the answer I was searching for, I just didn't knew what to wrtite in Google to get it. Also, thanks @teeyo for the advice.