# Is Putting Quotes on PHP Named Indexes Unnecessary?

Tags: php, arrays, indexed

Is the following:

```
$arr = [
    foo => 'bar',
    bar => 'foo'
];
```

The same as:

```
$arr = [
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'bar' => 'foo'
];
```

In other words, is putting quotes on named indexes unnecessary? When would be the only times when putting quotes on string indexes be really needed?

Comment: Doesn't your first version throw warnings?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2406006/354577

Comment: Turn PHP notices on - the unquoted version is trying to use constants named `foo` and `bar`. The default behaviour until PHP 7.2 was to raise a notice and fall back to the name of the constant. This has now been increased to a warning, and will likely stop working as of PHP 8. In short, this is never (and has never been) a good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first example should throw a *NOTICE*. If you do not use quotes then PHP will look for a constant with that name.

```
php > $myArr = [abc => 'hello'];
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant abc - assumed 'abc' in php shell code on line 1
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() php shell code:0

Notice: Use of undefined constant abc - assumed 'abc' in php shell code on line 1

Call Stack:
    9.7779     350840   1. {main}() php shell code:0
```

---

I ran this example in PHP 7.1.8, however in PHP 7.2 [this has been deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate-bareword-strings).

Comment: This is just a notice (not an error) in PHP 7.1 and earlier and a warning in PHP 7.2. [There's a proposal to deprecate the behaviour entirely in PHP 8](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate-bareword-strings).

Comment: Good, hopefully they *do* remove it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP converts "bare strings" into proper strings, but will give you a warning. It is likely that this functionality will disappear in future.

If you really, really want to do this (you shouldn't), it will work as log as the string matches the [format for a constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php), which is the regex

```
[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*
```

(Don't do it. Just don't.)