# Insert Data into database with HTML, PHP, AJAX

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I have a HTML form with action to a PHP file (insert.php). This PHP file is inserting my form values into the database (MySQL).

HTML

```
<form method="post" id="myForm" action="insert.php">
First Name:<input type="text" name="Fname" id="Fname" maxlength="12" size="12"/> <br/>
Mark1:<input type="text" name="Mark1" id="Mark1" maxlength="12" size="12"/> <br/>
<p><input type="submit" id="myButton" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
<div id="someElement">Response is Here:</div>
```

the insert.php file is -->

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","student");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO student_details (full_name, mark1) VALUES ('$_POST[Fname]', '$_POST[Mark1]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

There is no problem in data insertion with the above scenario.

I tried the same to do with AJAX and I don't see any result

my Ajax code -->

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#myButton").click(function() { 
    alert("am in the function now");
        $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'insert.php',
        data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
        success: function(d) {
            $("#someElement").html(d);
        }
        });
    }); 
});

</script>
```

Kindly help me out where I am missing the logic. I am guessing that I am missing something basic somewhere. It's been almost two days of time on this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: either split variables from a string `"...".$_POST[Fname]."..."` or use curly brackets around them `"...{$_POST[Fname]}..."` otherwise they wont evaluate

Comment: 1. Use `var_dump($_POST)` to debug; 2. By stuffing everything into SQL query, you missed the point of using MySQLi. Use prepared statement and variable binding.

Comment: did you get the `alert('am in the function now')`?

Comment: So used to using mysql_* that I didn't spot that! :-)

Comment: what your `console` says

Comment: @Paw Cabelin: no I am not getting that "alert". I intentionally used that alert to see whether am entering that function.

Comment: that means you havent had any connection with your script yet. pls recheck your inclusions like **paths, filenames, variables, ids**

Comment: @user1397891 please replace your `<input type='submit'>` to `<input type='button'>` you shouldnt use **Submit** since you're using AJAX you may also want remove that `action=''` in your **form tag**

Comment: @PawCabelin: yes I did change type to button and removed the action in form. 
Connection with script.. I made sure everything's in place... not sure where the problem is... :(

Comment: @PawCabelin : dude I got the problem place.... It's the problem with inheriting JQUERY... I used version 1.6.4 till now which gave me this nonsense stuff. I changed it to 1.9 and it's working like magic.

Comment: still didnt get the alert? what browser are you using? better if you're using **chrome** you could use **inspect element** check the **Console** tab. usually it reports common errors

Comment: ok glad you made it. more wisdom! :)

Answer (score 1):

you should prevent default submit form action

```
$("#myButton").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
...
```

Comment: fix the PHP too and you'll have a complete answer that can be accepted

Comment: read the comments. `mysqli_prepare()` the SQL as it wont currently work with arrays in quotes

Comment: @Waygood, it was not the problem, OP says `I used version 1.6.4 till now which gave me this nonsense stuff. I changed it to 1.9 and it's working like magic.`

Answer (score 1):

You should change

- `<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Submit" />`
- Also change
  `<form method="post" id="myForm" action="">`
- You should also check using `print_r()` for checking `$_POST array`.
- And try to `echo $sql exit;` your Query and run in `PhpMyadmin` for fixing values.
- Most important you should use `mysql_real_escape_string` for sanitize data and security.

Answer (score 0):

If I may suggest, use PHP5 PDO for working with databases.

[1]: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php php.net pdo

Comment: It's not an answer. Should be comment.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing quotes around index in **$_POST** array. Even though it worked in some cases, it may create problem.

Please have a look at these:

[Is it okay to use array[key] in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405482/is-it-okay-to-use-arraykey-in-php)

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be with your sql query. I don't know how did it work without ajax but your should put the index position of $_POST array in single quotes. such as `$_POST['name']`; Better approach would be, storing them in variables and use these variables instead.

Also change `$("#button").click` to `$("#button").event("click", function(){.....})`.