# How to file put contents to textfile with USER:PASS format?

Tags: php

I am trying to save the $_Get, user:pass to text file in my website.

I am sorry but am not a php dev. so i've come with following code:

```
<?php
   if( $_GET["user"] || $_GET["pass"] ) {
        $file = 'somefile.txt';
        file_put_contents($file, $_GET["user"] . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
        file_put_contents($file, $_GET["pass"] . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
   }
?>
```

Now it save

```
User
pass
```

How to save it as

```
User:pass
```

Thank you,
regrads

Comment: Off-topic but passing credentials via `GET` request is not safe at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to create a string in the required format. For example

```
file_put_contents($file, "$_GET[user]:$_GET[pass]" . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

**Note:** within a double-quoted string, associative array indexes do **not** need to be quoted.

See here for an example ~ https://3v4l.org/Fr30Y

---

Your script can trigger potential `E_NOTICE` level errors around undefined indexes so if you want to play it safe, I would make sure both `user` and `pass` indexes exist by changing

```
if( $_GET["user"] || $_GET["pass"] ) {
```

to

```
if ( isset($_GET['user'], $_GET['pass']) ) {
```

Comment: I think you may need curly braces around the variables, but maybe there are cases where you don't.

Comment: @CMiller nope, not in this case

Comment: The only thing you would want to look out for is if there is a defined keyword that matches the array key. If so it will replace the key name with the key word. The way to prevent that would be "{$_GET['user']}:{$_GET['pass']}".

Comment: @CMiller that is completely unnecessary. I suggest you read the manual. See http://php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#example-52

Comment: I just tested it by defining a keyword and the keyword replaces the array key. There is even a question covering it on this site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405482/is-it-okay-to-use-arraykey-in-php

Comment: @CMiller did you test it within a double-quoted string? I bet you didn't

Comment: @CMiller on that question, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5059548/283366) mentions the same difference as I have

Comment: You are correct. keywords don't work in double quotes.

Comment: @phil I have a small question, do you mind to know how to decode_base64 now the $_Get[1], $_Get[2] ?

Comment: @mzabox really not sure what you mean but PHP has the [`base64_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.base64-decode.php) function